# How to find the number of days between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a basic query:

```
SELECT dtCreated
    , bActive
    , dtLastPaymentAttempt
    , dtLastUpdated
    , dtLastVisit
FROM Customers
WHERE (bActive = 'true') 
    AND (dtLastUpdated > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-0100:00:00', 102))
```

I want to add another column to the output... lets call it "Difference" to find out the number of days between 'dtcreated' and 'dtlastupdated'  So for example if record 1 has a dtcreated of 1/1/11 and dtlastupdated is 1/1/12 the "Difference" column would be "365".

Can this be accomplished in a query?

Comment: Googling "How to find the number of days between two dates query" found multitudes of answers.  That's what you should try first.

Comment: @Jeremy, isn't it good to have an answer here? Google in fact just brought me here.

Comment: @AdrianMouat keep in mind this is more than a year after the question was asked.  StackOverflow does enjoy higher ranked search results on Google, so this is a natural result... regardless of the fact that it wasn't necessary.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You would use [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime

set @start = '2011-01-01'
set @end = '2012-01-01'

select DATEDIFF(d, @start, @end)

results = 365
```

so for your query:

```
SELECT dtCreated
    , bActive
    , dtLastPaymentAttempt
    , dtLastUpdated
    , dtLastVisit
    , DATEDIFF(d, dtCreated, dtLastUpdated) as Difference
FROM Customers
WHERE (bActive = 'true') 
    AND (dtLastUpdated > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-0100:00:00', 102))
```

Comment: I get an error on this... SQL Execution Error Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string

Comment: @Shmewnix what is the datatype for `dtCreated` and `dtLastUpdated`?  If they are not datetime, then you will need to convert them.

Comment: where would you convert them? In the select statement? or in the datediff statement?

Comment: You would need to convert them in the `datediff` statement.

Comment: Would I be Converting each? so something like:
DateDiff (d, dtcreated Convert (Datetime), Dtlastupdated Convert(Datetime) as difference?

Comment: You would use datediff(d, cast(dtcreated as datetime), cast(dtlastupdated as datetime))

Comment: it was actually related to the convert statement... at the end (1/1/12) Once I removed that, and ran the query it was fine. I then added the final convert and it works fine.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Greate.. It is really helpful For me

Answer (score 10):

To find the number of days between two dates, you use:

```
DATEDIFF ( d, startdate , enddate )
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the DATE_DIFF function to provide this value as below:

```
SELECT dtCreated
    , bActive
    , dtLastPaymentAttempt
    , dtLastUpdated
    , dtLastVisit
    , DATEDIFF(d, dtLastUpdated, dtCreated) AS Difference
FROM Customers
WHERE (bActive = 'true') 
    AND (dtLastUpdated > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-0100:00:00', 102))
```

EDIT: IF using MySQL you omit the 'd' leaving you with

```
DATEDIFF(dtLastUpdated, dtCreated) AS Difference
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL there is the DATEDIFF function which calculate the days between two dates:

```
SELECT dtCreated
    , bActive
    , dtLastPaymentAttempt
    , dtLastUpdated
    , dtLastVisit
    , DATEDIFF(dtLastUpdated, dtCreated) as Difference
FROM Customers
WHERE (bActive = 'true') 
    AND (dtLastUpdated > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-0100:00:00', 102))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATEDIFF(d, 'Start Date', 'End Date')
```

do it

Answer (score 0):

The **DATEDIFF** function is use to calculate the number of days between the required date

Example if you are diff current date from given date in string format

```
SELECT * , DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),STR_TO_DATE('01/11/2017', '%m/%d/%Y')) AS days FROM consignments WHERE code = '1610000154'
```

Here, **STR_TO_DATE** () : Take a string and returns a date specified by a format mask;

For your example :

```
SELECT dtCreated
    , bActive
    , dtLastPaymentAttempt
    , dtLastUpdated
    , dtLastVisit
    , DATEDIFF(dtLastUpdated, dtCreated) as Difference
FROM Customers
WHERE (bActive = 'true') 
    AND (dtLastUpdated > '2012-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Tested on mysql server 5.7.17

Answer (score 0):

As @Forte L. mentioned you can do the following as well;

```
SELECT dtCreated
    , bActive
    , dtLastPaymentAttempt
    , dtLastUpdated
    , dtLastVisit

    , DATEDIFF(day, dtCreated, dtLastUpdated) Difference

FROM Customers
WHERE (bActive = 'true') 
    AND (dtLastUpdated > CONVERT(DATETIME, '2012-01-0100:00:00', 102))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Firstdate DATE='2016-04-01',
 @LastDate DATE=GETDATE(),/*get today date*/
 @resultDay int=null

SET @resultDay=(SELECT DATEDIFF(d, @Firstdate, @LastDate))
PRINT @resultDay
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get No of Days between two days**

```
DECLARE @date1 DATE='2015-01-01',
 @date2 DATE='2019-01-01',
 @Total int=null

SET @Total=(SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @date1, @date2))
PRINT @Total
```

Comment: Greate.. It is really helpful For me

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEDIFF('Start Date', 'End Date')
```

In MySQL, This gave me the difference in Days.