# Calculating the days between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

In my database, I have a column that looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

And I need to try and filter the entries in this table by whether they are 30/60/90 days from the date selected by the user.

Here is my current SQL query that I have written in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT 
    Account, DCBalance, (SUM(Credit) - SUM(Debit)) AS '30day' 
FROM 
    [Graceland Estates BC].[dbo].[PostGL] AS gl
INNER JOIN 
    [Graceland Estates BC].[dbo].[Client] ON gl.DrCrAccount = Client.DCLink 
WHERE 
    DrCrAccount = 15 AND AccountLink <> '2'
    AND TxDate > 2021-11-30  
GROUP BY
    Account, DCBalance
```

In this code `(SUM(Credit) - SUM(Debit))` is the balance for that time period that needs to be printed. `DrCrAccount` decides which user the balance belongs to.

Does anyone know how to determine the amount (in days) from the database entry ?

Comment: Use `datediff()` function perhaps?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the number of days between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418496/how-to-find-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: Though `DATEDIFF` will do it, I suspect the OP will want `DATEADD` on the parameter's value. A `DATEDIFF` on a column in the `WHERE` and parameter will not be SARGable.

Comment: Side Note: Don't use single quotes (`'`) for aliases. Single Quotes are for literal strings, not object names. Although the syntax works for aliasing, some methods are deprecated. It is also the *only* place it works (`ORDER BY '30day'` for example would *not* order by the column aliased as `'30day'` but return the rows in an arbitrary order) and it can be confusing to new (and even old) users to SQL. Use object names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you "must" then use either the T-SQL identify (brackets (`[]`)), or ANSI SQL identify (double quotes (`"`)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```sql
WITH some_cte AS (
  SELECT Account
       , DCBalance
       , Credit
       , Debit
       , CASE
           WHEN TxDate >= DateAdd(dd, -30, GetDate()) THEN '0-30'
           WHEN TxDate >= DateAdd(dd, -60, GetDate()) THEN '30-60'
           WHEN TxDate >= DateAdd(dd, -90, GetDate()) THEN '60-90'
           ELSE '90+'
         END AS date_period
  ...
  WHERE TxDate >= DateAdd(dd, -90, GetDate())
)
SELECT Account
     , DCBalance
     , date_period
     , Sum(Credit) - Sum(Debit) As balance
FROM   some_cte
GROUP
    BY Account
     , DCBalance
     , date_period
;
```